# extracting last elements from 2d array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Ok so I'm trying to create a very basic machine translation program in JavaScript as a learning project.  I am breaking sentences into 2D arrays ala...

```
function string2TwoD(sentence){
    var periodless = sentence.replace(/^[.\s]+|[.\s]+$/g, "");
    var splitSen = periodless.split(" ");
    splitArray = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < splitSen.length; i++){
        splitArray[i] = splitSen[i].split("");
    }
    return splitArray;
}
```

now I am trying to extract the last letter from each second level array and stick them in another array that I can work with later.
So far the only thing I've come up with is...

```
var workWith = sting2TwoD("This here is a sentence boy.");
var completeSen = string2TwoD("This here is a sentence boy.");
var i;
var popped = [];
    for (i = 0; i < workwith.length; i++){
        popped += workwith[i].pop();
    }
var poppedArray = popped.split("");
console.log(poppedArray);
console.log(completeSen);
```

This seems like a crappy solution to me as I am forced to create a second copy of the original array just to hold on to the original value of my string2TwoD function.  There must be a better way to access the ending values of the second level arrays (in many cases I will need the last two elements of the arrays as I am actually trying to extract adjective endings(this will be translating from German into English)).  I've tried doing it with multiple for loops but I just can't seem to get it to pull out the correct values.  Any suggestions?  Forgive me, I am noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Takes the `workWith` array and pushes the last element to a new array.

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0, l = workWith.length; i < l; i++) {
  arr.push(workWith[i][workWith[i].length - 1]);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: this one worked well for me easy for me to follow and it still allows me to keep my 2d array which I intend on using again later when I am have the program perform the actual translation.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed,

You can access the last value of any JS array by using:

```
arrayName[arrayName.length-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the problem 1D :

`myString.slice(0,-1)` will removes the last char of a string, thus you don't need to transform the string into an array. See its documentation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) (positive index: we count from the beginning, negative index: we count from the end)

Then to be elegant, you should map the function above to the 1D array (it means you automatically apply the function to every element of the table and replace its value by the returned value):

```
/* STEP 1: standardization, on some web browsers the array.prototype.map function may not exist */
if (!Array.prototype.map)
{
  Array.prototype.map = function(fun /*, thisp*/)
  {
    var len = this.length;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var res = new Array(len);
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in this)
        res[i] = fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this);
    }

    return res;
  };
}

/* STEP 2 */
splitSen.map(
  function(element)
  {
    element.slice(0,-1);
  }
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm using this correctly.  I just ended up chopping off the last letter/word of the sentence.  Also when I tried mapping the function to splitSen rather than applying it directly it just returned a bunch of undefined values...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `workWith` to achieve this goal :

```
var item;
var lastChars = [];
var completeSen = string2TwoD("This here is a sentence boy.");
for (var i = 0, l = completeSen.length; i < l; i++) {
    item = completeSen[i];
    lastChars.push(item[item.length - 1]);
}
console.log(lastChars);
console.log(completeSen);
```